# ImageMagick command sometimes fails

Tags: linux, nfs, imagemagick

I have an ImageMagick command that is something like this:

```
convert "/path/to/photo" -set comment "(c) my company" -resize WxH miff:- | composite -dissolve 30 -geometry +40+138 -quality 80 "/path/to/logo.miff" - jpeg:"/path/to/photo_for_public"
```

Directory `/path/to` is mounted over `NFS` (same network). Some options of `fstab` that might be helpful:

- Both `rsize` and `wsize` are 3kB
- `hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2`

Sometimes the `imagemagick` command fails and produces no file (`/path/to/photo_for_public` might not emerge after command execution). Files might be from 100kB to 10MB. We usually re-run the command for files not generated. Sometimes it fails even twice, so we do it third time (hilariously funny, but even a third run can fail).

Are there any thoughts what may be wrong with my photo-processing setup?

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is: Where's the error message?  I would expect your convert and composite commands to say *something* when they break.

Second thought is to break things up into separate operations for debugging:

1. copy from NFS to local

   convert local to local temp file

   composite local temp file to local temp file

   copy from local to NFS

and then watch how far it gets in the process.